# Pandas iterating over multiple rows in single columns.... how to avoid 40+ elif statements?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list

I have a CSV File that's 78 columns by about 400,000. A simplified example is below:
'''

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3,4],
                 'Y':[0,0,1,1],
                 'Z':[0,0,0,0],
          'Location':[1,2,3,4],
             'Data1':[123,645,324,876]
             'Data2':[733,347,547,764]
             'Data3':[245,846,435,099]
             'Data4':[748,664,222,810]}
```

'''

Get rid of the loc key deprecation thingy when trying to use keys for the columns:
'''

```
headers=df.keys().tolist()
df=df.reindex(columns=headers)
```

'''

I need to produce an output that repeats X, Y, Z for each value of 'Location' while rotating 'Data1' - 'Data4'.

Seems the melt function is good for that,

'''

```
df2=pd.melt(df, id_vars=['X','Y','Z'], value_vars=['Location', 'Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3', 'Data4'], value_name='Measurements')
```

'''
End up with a data format I need before the math transformation.
'''

```
X        Y        Z        variable        Measurements
1        0        0        Data1           123
2        0        0        Data1           645

... (Many Rows Later)

4        1        0        Data4           810
```

'''

**Now I need to do the actual math that this question is about**

How I have 48 types of variables from Data1-Data48. I need to modify the Z field by whatever the Data field is (I'm making a point cloud for some geological modeling/visualization). The only way I can think to do it is to have 48 if statements and evaluate each one in a loop and add to the Z column the appropriate offset...

Now, this seems hella inefficient and there HAS to be another way, I've tried to google my way out of this and am really having no luck at all.

Comment: Use a dict and use the key to find the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume that you have a dictionnary mapping the `variable` field to an offset:

```
delta = {'Data1': 3, 'Data2': 5, 'Data3': 7, 'Data4': 9, 'Location': 0}
```

We can build an auxiliary dataframe from it:

```
aux = pd.Series(delta, name='offset').to_frame().rename_axis('variable').reset_index()
```

It gives here:

```
   variable  offset
0     Data1       3
1     Data2       5
2     Data3       7
3     Data4       9
4  Location       0
```

We can now simply add the relevant offset to the `Z` field in a vectorized way:

```
df2['Z'] += df2.merge(aux, how='left', on='variable')['offset']
```

to get:

```
    X  Y  Z  variable  Measurements
0   1  0  0  Location             1
1   2  0  0  Location             2
2   3  1  0  Location             3
3   4  1  0  Location             4
4   1  0  3     Data1           123
5   2  0  3     Data1           645
6   3  1  3     Data1           324
7   4  1  3     Data1           876
8   1  0  5     Data2           733
9   2  0  5     Data2           347
10  3  1  5     Data2           547
11  4  1  5     Data2           764
12  1  0  7     Data3           245
13  2  0  7     Data3           846
14  3  1  7     Data3           435
15  4  1  7     Data3            99
16  1  0  9     Data4           748
17  2  0  9     Data4           664
18  3  1  9     Data4           222
19  4  1  9     Data4           810
```